# Pass DateTime variable to Edit.cstml to display and select from datepicker

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, datepicker

I have the following fragment of view Edit.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Property BirthDate is type of DateTime.
When I want edit BirthDate, it displays me only only format rrrr-mm-dd with no data, but with possibility of choice date from datepicker. When I add

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Then I receive format yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS with data, but I can't select date from datepicker.

What should I do, to get date in format yyyy-mm-dd and have possibility to select date from datepicker?

Comment: Try to use Data annotation in your BirthDate property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Model` add the following model property.

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BirthDate{ get; set; }
```